# Is there an alternative to a foreach statement?

Tags: c#

I want to do a foreach on each child in my app.config but there is no public definition for 'GetEnumerator' in System.ServiceModel.Configuration.CustomBindingCollectionElement I would not ask if this were my own class, but it is a System one. Is there something I can use instead of the foreach to loop through each child in the BindingsSection?

This is what I want to perform the foreach on

```
BindingsSection bindingsSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/bindings") as BindingsSection;
```

Comment: Which child elements are you trying to loop through? The `BindingCollections`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BindingCollections` is a `List` that has a method called `ForEach`, so you can do something like this:

```
bindingsSection.BindingCollections.ForEach( e => {do something here});
```

Comment: It's iterable using a `foreach` construct as well. That said, `ForEach()` is indeed a `List<>` extension method.

Comment: @BoltClock - That is correct. You can use foreach as well, but he asked for an *alternative* to a foreach loop, and the ForEach *method* is just that (Note that ForEach is a method on List<T> and not a extension method)

Comment: Thanks. This is the method that I have used, and it has worked very well thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `foreach`, but you loop through its `BindingCollections` property, like this:

```
BindingsSection bindingsSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/bindings") as BindingsSection;

foreach (BindingCollectionElement collection in bindingsSection.BindingCollections)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have not used this answer, but it was interesting to know it can be done like this.